# How to set validation based on field selection in angular reactive form array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

i try to implement angular reactive form array validation on based on other filed

```
    private addUserFormGroup(): FormGroup {
            return new FormGroup({
                'name': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                'emailAddress': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                'admin': new FormControl(false, Validators.required),
                'role': new FormControl(''),
            });
        }
        
         ngOnInit(): void {
            this.addUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                userList: this.formBuilder.array([this.addUserFormGroup()]),
            });
            
            this.addUserForm.valueChanges.subscribe((c) => {
                c.userList.forEach((x) => {
                    console.log(x.admin);
                    x['role'].validator = Validators.required;
                    // x.role.setValidators(Validators.required);
                });
            
            
            }
```

basically admin formcontrol as a checkbox, if i select admin checkbox i need to apply Validators.required to role filed.

could you please he me on this

Comment: You would need to call a function, passing in the index of the addUserForm you want to change the validators on. Otherwise, you would need to add a valueChanges subscription *for each addUserForm* and change the validators.

Comment: Could please give me some examples on how to do

Comment: How about you follow the function-based advice I gave you, and if you're stuck in the implementation you can provide what you've tried and we can help you from there? S.O. isn't really a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to valueChanges of FormControl "admin" only so that it wont trigger on any other value changes.

And in subscribed method based on value true or false you can set the validator with setValidators function.

Inside value changes subscribed method you can either find the FormControl "role" using parent property of FormControl "admin"

or

if the structure is fixed you can get FormControl "role" with path also, like `this.addUserForm.get("userList").get("0").get("role").setValidators(Validators.required);`

Comment: You would have to do this for every form in the `userList` array

Comment: i try this this.addUserForm.get('userList').get('0').get('role').setValidators(Validators.required); but i got the console error as => ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setValidators')